# Which Google Maps API key should I use for using web services on Android/iOS?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to develop apps on iOS/Android that use [Google Maps API Web Services's Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro) (since there are no Direction function in either the iOS or the Android API), following is the API I am using.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=API_KEY
```

Currently I am using the "Server API key" and allowing requests from all ip addresses. But we wonder if it can be done in a more security way, and fill the Android/iOS key inside.

Comment: This is a web service call, you have to use the `Server Key`, with `Server Key` you can still limit IP address.

Comment: Thank you @ztan, I guess I would have to go with the Server Key